# Problems with shiny-server.conf to mapping urls dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm working with shiny-server, and I'm looking for a solution for a problem with a shiny-server.conf, I need map a lot of apps dinamically, and due that I'm using a shiny-server.conf, so how am I doing it?, I use regular expressions, but I don't know if shiny-server does not support it or I do it bad, this is my shiny-server.conf file.

```
shiny-server.conf

run_as shiny;
log_dir /var/shiny-server/log;

server{
 listen 80 172.23.177.37;
 location /{
  site_dir /var/shiny-server/www/managment_server;
 }

 location /sipgo?n=1{
  site_dir /var/shiny-server/www;
 }
}
```

I have some apps that begin with the same name "sipgo" but continue with other character "sipgo1", "sipgo2".... so, when I put those, in the shiny-server.conf, can I use "/location" with regular expresion?

exactly the problem is in " location /sipgo?n=1"  because this is the form how I'm mapping urls

Once again, thank you kindly.